Apache Iceberg Java SDK: is org.apache.iceberg.Table object thread-safe?
I have a Java service, that consumes messages in multiple threads and produces some output data. I want to export that data to Iceberg table, using AWS Glue as a catalog implementation.
My guess is that GlueCatalog object looks thread-safe, so I can instantiate it once per application. But what about the Table object? Can it be shared as well? Or should I call catalog.loadTable() in each exporter thread?
Currently I am considering creating a Table instance per exporter, but I am not sure if that's an optimal approach.
